# Lemon liqueur has gas?

Tags: alcohol

I tried to make some sort of liqueur with homemade lemonade. I added lemon juice, sugar and a little vodka. I left it for 2 months in a dark and cool place and as soon as I opened it turned out it contained gas (a lot of it). I tasted it and it's like sparkling lemonade with alcohol. Where did the gas came from and is it ok to consume?

Comment: You might want to look up recipes for 'limoncello'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gas is likely due to fermentation of the sugars by wild yeasts which are present almost everywhere.  This is the standard method for production of alcoholic beverages, although specific yeast strains are used.  It is obvious that there was insufficient vodka to prevent yeast growth.

As far as consuming; there is no way outside of a lab to determine the yeasts and their products, as well as any bacteria - and their products - that may have participated.  As such, I would hesitate to consume it.